# 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer on groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, scipy

Can someone please explain why I'm getting this error when I'm doing a lingress (slope) on 'day' and 'value' which are both numeric datatype. 
Below is my script:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import linregress
y = pd.DataFrame({'entity':['a','a','b','b','b','c'],
                          'day':[1999,2004,2003,2007,2014, 2016],
                          'value':[2,5,3,2,7,8]})
mylist= ['a', 'b'] 
y1 = y.groupby('entity').apply(lambda x: x[x['entity'].isin(mylist)])
```

This line gives error:

```
y1.apply(lambda v: linregress(v['day'], v['value']))
```

error trace:

> > TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> >     last)
> >     /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py in
> >     get_value(self, series, key)
> >         999             try:
> >     -> 1000                 return libindex.get_value_at(s, k)    1001             except IndexError:
> >
> > pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.get_value_at()
> >
> > pandas/_libs/src/util.pxd in util.get_value_at()
> >
> > TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
> >
> > During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> >
> > KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> >     last)  in ()
> >     ----> 1 y1.apply(lambda v: linregress(v['day'], v['value']))
> >           2
>
> KeyError: ('day', 'occurred at index entity')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update, then you need this:

```
y1.groupby(level='entity').apply(lambda x: linregress(x['day'],x['value']))
```

Output:

```
entity
a                                                                 (0.6, -1197.3999999999999, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
b    (0.4032258064516129, -805.6774193548387, 0.8485552916276634, 0.35494576760559776, 0.25142673013096595)
dtype: object
```

I think all you need is to do this, you do not need to apply, just pass the two dataframe columns to `linregress`:

```
linregress(y1['day'],y1['value'])
```

Output:

```
LinregressResult(slope=0.29073482428115016, intercept=-579.2396166134187, rvalue=0.7502746874224853, pvalue=0.14406233411953523, stderr=0.1479110164470003)
```

Comment: This doesn't give the slope for groups 'a' and 'b'

Answer (score 0):

Note the [documentation for linregress](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) calls for array-like type inputs.

An array-like type here means any data structure that can be coerced into a NumPy array. This includes Pandas Series (we can show this by calling `np.array` on one).

So you can call `linregress` directly on the dataframe columns, no need for apply here. That is, you can replace the last line of your code with

```
df = y[y['entity'].isin(mylist)]
linregress(df['day'], df['value'])
```

The adavantage of Pandas and many of the libraries in the Python data ecosystem is that they play nicely together, and that they are [array-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming), meaning they are optimized for operations over arrays and other large iterable data structures versus scalar values, so for the most part their methods take those data structures by default without requiring you to explicitly call `apply`, `map`, and other functions.

Another note: the type error you're seeing is a stack trace internal to Pandas. The most recent trace and the direct cause for your issue as at the bottom.

Comment: But I need the slope for different groups, 'a' and 'b'.

Comment: Im not sure I follow, it's still returning a single value for slope, but I should be getting a list...

Comment: `linregress` returns a `LinregressResult` object that provides methods for accessing the slope, intercepts and other data for the inputs provided. It is expected that slope will be scalar/a single value because if you have two coordinates `x` and `y`, slope is going to be a scalar value. What exactly are you trying to find out?

Comment: so I guess what I was expecting is since I have data belonging to entity 'a' and entity 'b' groups. It should compute the slope for both groups and return a list. For instance, this is my dataframe:                                  
      entity, day, value
0 (a 1999 2)
1 (a 2004 5)
2 (b 2003 3)
3 (b 2007 2)
4 (b 2014 7)   ,                                                                              so it should find the slope for first set ([x= 1999,2004], [y=2,5]) and then the second set ([x=2003, 2007, 2014], [y=3,2,7])